# Tampermonkey script influneces script from website and doesn't let it make ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I just wrote a small script for a website to hide an element that contains advertising (It's a gaming website which shows buying options for the game they are writing about). What's weird is, that the script works fine. I only set the CSS property `display` to `none`. It works as aspected and this should not break CSS or javascript selectors. But when the script is enabled it doesn't let me click on images (to view them in a cinema mode) or start videos.

I get the following message, when clicking on such media elements:

```
gamestar.min.js?cc=310520171659:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at openLightbox (gamestar.min.js?cc=310520171659:1)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (gamestar.min.js?cc=310520171659:1)
    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLBodyElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Without the script it loads via an Ajax request the media correctly:

```
jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "http://www.gamestar.de/gs_cb/index.cfm?event=content%3Aajax.zoom&id=132536&…Star+Wars%3A+Battlefront+2%3C%2Fb%3E%3Cbr%3E+Reveal+Screenshot+1&clicked=1".
```

How is it possible that the script intefers with the website in such a way? And how can I prevent this?

Here is my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Better Gamestar
// @namespace    k-ruben
// @version      1.0
// @description  Disable Buying options
// @author       You
// @match        http://www.gamestar.de/*
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var offerteaser = $(".offerteaser-box").parent().parent();
        offerteaser.css("display", "none");
    });
})();
```

Comment: Don't use `@grant none` unless you really need an easy-peasy access to the page functions without unsafeWindow hassle.

Comment: wow, cool. That solved it. I don't know for what `grant` is, but I will know start looking into it. `grant: none` was always pre-written from tampermonkey so I thought it would be fine and I had never problems with it before.